# Create file, serve for download, delete file on button click, Django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I have some data that can be used to create a png image if needed. I am trying not to create the png file anywhere unless the user requests the download. I was able to get the downloading to work successfully with:

```
    <a href="{% static 'analyze/images/temp.png' %}"
       download="x_vs_y.png" style="padding: 5px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Download Plot">
    </a>
```

However, this approach requires the file to already exist somewhere at the 'analyze/images/temp.png' path.

I would like to call a separate Django view to do the following:

1. create the necessary file in a temp folder
2. Serve the file for download (similar to how the href download works)
3. delete the temp folder
4. return to original view, the user has the file now

I am unsure how to do the 1-3 steps. I thought about calling the view, creating the file, and giving the path of the file. This can then be downloaded with something similar to the following javascript example:

```
        <script> 
            function download(file, text) { 

                //creating an invisible element 
                var element = document.createElement('a'); 
                element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' 
                                     + encodeURIComponent(text)); 
                element.setAttribute('download', file); 

                //the above code is equivalent to 
                // <a href="path of file" download="file name"> 

                document.body.appendChild(element); 

                //onClick property 
                element.click(); 

                document.body.removeChild(element); 
            } 

            // Start file download. 
            document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() { 
                // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content 
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value; 
                var filename = "GFG.txt"; 

                download(filename, text); 
            }, false); 
        </script>
```

But then once this is done the file will still exist, taking up space. Is there a solution to this or am I missing some key concept of web development and file usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create a view that takes the name of the file that you want to convert

```
def get_converted_png(request):
    try:
        filename = request.GET['filename']
        filedata = request.GET['filedata']
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404 # or another exception...
```

There are a couple of solutions to this, they depend on the size of the file and how the file is generated

The first actually does not require any temporary files at all and should be slightly faster, if the file is too big or you cannot generate the file easily in a python method it may not be appropriate. It uses the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) module

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import FileResponse


def get_converted_png(request):
    try:
        filename = request.GET['filename']
        filedata = request.GET['filedata']
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404 # or another exception...

    # This create an in-memory file object
    converted_png = BytesIO(method_that_converts_the_file(filedata))
    return FileResponse(converted_png, filename=filename)
```

If you have to save the file to disk because of memory limitations you should look at the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module for writing the file to a tempfile first. An example:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from django.http import FileResponse


def get_converted_png(request):
    try:
        filename = request.GET['filename']
        filedata = request.GET['filedata']
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404 # or another exception...

    with converted_png as TemporaryFile():
        converted_png.write(method_that_converts_the_file(filedata))
        return FileResponse(converted_png, filename=filename)
```

Then you create the link to your view like this

```
<a href="{% url 'get_converted_png' %}?filename=x_vs_y.png&filedata=...">
    <button value="Download Plot" />
</a>
```

Comment: I have three questions for you, 1: What is the file size limit I should be using for this implementation? 2: What is the difference in using GET request vs passing something to the view method? 3: For converting a png to a BytesIO object, do I give it the path of the file? How does that work?

Comment: 1) basically the amount of available memory you have 2) what do you mean by passing something to the view method? Using query parameters IS sending something to the view method

Comment: Added an example for using temp files

Comment: Passing something to the view as an argument example:
The href = "{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}", The view: def vote(request, question_id): This would be useful to pass many things inside a dictionary rather than ?filename and ?filedata

Comment: You can always add more arguments to the view and the url definition

Comment: What does the urlpattern list look like for a view that only is meant for something like this? The entry, path('', views.download_plot_png, name='download_plot_png') doesn't seem to be correct.